# ios/mobileconfig ikev2 ondemand via apple configurator 2

Tags: ios, vpn, apple-configurator

I am trying to use Apple Configurator 2 downloaded from AppStore, and I cannot find ondemand settings in the vpn section. Please help. I can manually add ondemand section to my plist and it works. If I open this plist, Apple Configurator does not remove this section, so I assume it knows and recognizes it.

The settings are as simple as that:

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Disconnect</string>
        <key>InterfaceTypeMatch</key>
        <string>WiFi</string>
        <key>SSIDMatch</key>
        <array>
            <string>myWifi</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Ignore</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But I cannot find it in the Apple Configurator 2! Here's the same file opened in the AC2:
[image]

Please tell me, how to configure it using AC2?

Comment: This is exactly how I do it. AFAIK, on-demand cannot be configured via the Apple Configurator 2.

Comment: @not2savvy as I remember, it was possible with previous version. Not sure though

Comment: I did the same in the previous version, so I‘d say rather not.

Comment: Ok, strange, thank you! Just wonder why apple omits that